# Cannot install EasyTether on Ubuntu 12.4 because install button is greyed-out/unclickable

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation, easytether

I have copied the EasyTether software to my computer. When I attempt to install the package, the install button is greyed out and can't click on it.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you download the .deb file from http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.html?

Answer (score 1):

In the console, navigate to the directory the `.deb` file is in.

```
sudo dpkg -i easytether*
```